# Parse Endpoint Uri from CosmosDB connection string

Tags: .net, azure-cosmosdb

I have an environment variable containing a CosmosDB connection string, i.e. this format:

```
AccountEndpoint=https://ACCOUNTNAME.documents.azure.com:443/;AccountKey=STUFF==;
```

Before I connect to the native API (using [`CreateAndInitializeAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.cosmosclient.createandinitializeasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Cosmos_CosmosClient_CreateAndInitializeAsync_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IReadOnlyList_System_ValueTuple_System_String_System_String___Microsoft_Azure_Cosmos_CosmosClientOptions_System_Threading_CancellationToken_), I want to log the endpoint `Uri`, but can't find a parsing API.

What's the best approach, ideally with minimal code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `DbConnectionStringBuilder` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbconnectionstringbuilder?view=net-5.0)):

```
using System.Data.Common;

string connectionString = "AccountEndpoint=https://ACCOUNTNAME.documents.azure.com:443/;AccountKey=STUFF==;";
var builder = new DbConnectionStringBuilder
{
    ConnectionString = connectionString
};
string? endpoint = builder["AccountEndpoint"]?.ToString();
```

This is how the .NET SDK itself parses connection strings. ([source](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/024c12810c1e6f3d41139a0b5bc26b66f1fa520f/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/src/CosmosClientOptions.cs#L745))

Comment: While that would work now, I'm not terribly tempted to actually use it for real, as the implementation of that could diverge from the spec for CosmosDb connection strings over time. (But it works, so +1, thanks!)

Comment: Just added a note that this is how the SDK parses the connection strings. Seems like a pretty strong indicator that they would continue to keep a SQL-compliant format.

Comment: Yikes, nicely found, and very hard to argue with. I do wish there was a variant of it exposed, but I guess I can [shim it in a better way than before](https://github.com/jet/equinox/blob/v2/src/Equinox.Cosmos/Cosmos.fs#L1281-L1292) now.

Comment: So I logged https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/2328 ;)

Answer (score -1):

I know I can get the `.Endpoint` once I get the `CosmosClient` back

```
 let endpointUri : Uri = Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosClient(connStr).Endpoint
```

But that's way too heavy for my taste :(